# Setting playbackRate on firefox

Tags: firefox, html5-audio

How do I set the `playbackRate` in firefox? 
I have the following code:

```
audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.src = 'http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.ogg';
audio.playbackRate = 1.7;
audio.play();
console.log(audio.playbackRate); // Outputs 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `.play()` or `.load()` on the media item will (potentially) reset the `.playbackRate`.

Either set the `.playbackRate` afterwards, or use `.defaultPlaybackRate` instead.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sB6kV/2/) demonstrating that:

```
audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.src = 'http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.ogg';
audio.addEventListener("canplay", function () {
    audio.play();
    audio.playbackRate = 1.7;
    console.log(audio.playbackRate);
});
```

Comment: That's what I wound up doing. But the behavior doesn't make sense, and isn't consistent with chrome.